# Charts in Vaadin14 don't seem to automatically resize when in splitlayout windows

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

In Vaadin 14.4.2, I have a scenario in which I have added a chart inside a splitLayout. However, when I, as a user, expand or shrink the splitLayout, the corresponding chart does not resize. The other components, such as the grid do automatically resize. Is there some "magic" configuration option to get the chart to behave like other components? (The screenshot below shows the chart *not* having resized, even though the grid beneath it *did* properly automatically resize.) (Also fyi, I call this: `spectraChart.setSizeFull();` so the chart should be using up all the available space.) (Another FYI: I could probably "trap" the splitLayout resize even then redo the plotting, but it seems to me that this should ideally not be necessary in the a 'framework' solution such as Vaadin, since a chart is a component that should behave like other components, such as the grid.)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately that is true. You can workaround the issue by doing explicit JavaScript call to Charts to reflow when splitter position has been changed. The code snippet below finds all charts and reflows them:

```
innerLayout.addSplitterDragendListener(event -> {
getUI().ifPresent(
    ui -> ui.getPage()
       .executeJavaScript(
           "Array.from(window.document.getElementsByTagName('vaadin-chart')).forEach( el => el.__reflow());"
       ));                      
});
```